# How can I open current user browser by Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Python.
I want to open current user Chrome Browser.

```
ser = Service("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/chrome.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
```

But it opens new user Browser.
Please let me know the way.

Or, Please let me know the way to open Octo browser with Proxy info.

Comment: In general, it isn't possible to control a browser associated with user data for security reasons, since it could be used to steal your credentials. There might be ways around it, but it's very much not allowed by default.

Comment: If so, I can use the browser that has been opened?

Comment: use the built-in [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) library if you just want to display a page to a user.

Comment: Are you asking how to open a new *window* in an already running browser process?

Comment: Yes, Eventually I want to open the browser that's signed in by a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Octo API token when open the selenium.

Octobrowser account/ additionals: OCTO_API_TOKEN

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests

from config import *

# Get Profile uuid of OctoBrowser
def fnGetUUID():
    response_octo = requests.request("GET", OCTO_SEARCH_URL, headers=OCTO_HEADER)
    data_uuid = response_octo.json()
    uuid = data_uuid.get('data')[0]['uuid']
    return uuid

# Get Debug Port
# Profile id is uuid from fnGetUUID()
def get_debug_port(profile_id):
    data = requests.post(
        f'{LOCAL_API}/start', json={'uuid': profile_id, 'headless': False, 'debug_port': True}
    ).json()
    print(data)
    return data['debug_port']

# Create webdriver
# port is from get_debug_port()
def get_webdriver(port):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', f'127.0.0.1:{port}')
    # Change chrome driver path accordingly
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version = "114.0.5735.90").install(), options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def fnGetElementXpath(driver, flag, xpath):
    try:
        ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        if flag == False:
            return ele
        else:
            ele.click()
    except:
        print(f"fnGetElementXpath() is error because {xpath} can't find")
        return False

def fnGetElementsClass(driver, ClassName):
    try:
        eles = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, ClassName)))
        return eles
    except:
        print(f"fnGetElementXpath() is error because {ClassName} can't find")
        return False
profile_id = fnGetUUID()
port = get_debug_port(profile_id)
driver = get_webdriver(port)
driver.get(URL)
```

Reset this: OCTO_API_TOKEN AND OCTO_ID.
You can see the API_TOKEN in additional of the octo browser.

OCTO_API_TOKEN = '70f0212db1614b8598acbc8ad6e0f7f3'

OCTO_HTTP_SERVER = 58888

OCTO_ID = 'MS-Japa'

OCTO_SEARCH_URL =
'https://app.octobrowser.net/api/v2/automation/profiles?search={}'.format(OCTO_ID)

OCTO_HEADER = {
'X-Octo-Api-Token': OCTO_API_TOKEN
}

LOCAL_API = 'http://localhost:58888/api/profiles'

Comment: I can't find the OCTO_API_TOKEN info on my Octo browser.

Comment: How many proxies can you setting?
If you are using the have 10 proxies octo browser then you can`t use API_TOKEN.

Comment: You have to use more than 100+